# How do I print blank strings in PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, string

I tried using the '' or ' ' empty strings in PHP but it seems to have been trimmed when using the ***echo*** statement for displaying it in the browser.

```
echo '   the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy     dog.';
```

The statement above is been stripped of the white/blank spaces.

How can I do this in PHP? How can I print blank lines without them being stripped out?

Comment: Or put `<pre>` </pre>` around your text.

Comment: HTML browser condense multiple whitespace characters to one, if not in a `<pre>`-like environment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misconception about how browsers treat whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't stripping anything; your browser is ignoring the space. Right-click, View Source and you'll see what I mean. Either wrap the whole string in a `<pre>` tag, or use a *non-breaking space*, e.g., `&nbsp;`, for each piece of whitespace you want to leave. (Or use `style='white-space: pre;'` on the element.)

```
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp; the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; dog.';
```

Or:

```
echo '<pre>   the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy     dog.</pre>';
```

Or:

```
echo '<p style="white-space: pre;">   the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy     dog.</p>';
```

Or (@SecondRekudo):

> Or send a Content-type: text/plain header.

Which would look like:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Which needs to be called before any output to the browser (or you'll get a warning and the header won't be sent).

Comment: Or send a `Content-type: text/plain` header.

Comment: @SecondRikudo - True enough.